# Change a netCDF file with lots of variables

Tags: python, shell, julia, netcdf

Supposing a netCDF with lots of variables, such as an output file from climate model. And I hope to change one of the variable variable and save **all of them** into another file.

There are some optional methods such `nco` or `cdo`, `xarray` package in Python. However, the calculation may be complex and it's hard to use `nco`. The `xarray` method may be convenient for calculation but it takes too much time and I'm seeking for a faster way. Now I'm using `Julia` with `NCDataset(ofile, "a")` method but this method cannot save the "Dataset" into another file and it takes much of time in `I/O`.

I think the bottleneck comes from the `I/O` speed in reading a relatively large file. Is there a faster way I can accelerate the script especially for `I/O`?

P.S. The Python script I used looks like this:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(i_file)
plev = ds["lev"]
rad_temp = ds["rad_temp"]
                
new_var = rad_temp[:, lev, :, :] + 1

ds.to_netcdf(out_file)
```

I tried a very simple calculation such as `new_var = rad_temp[:, lev, :, :] + 1` and the speed is still unacceptable (about 1 minute for a 5Gb file).

Comment: could you clarify, what is actually the bottleneck here, the calculation you perform or file IO? I don't see much remedy for the latter on the software-side if you create a new, updated file, but regarding the calculation you might want to add some more details here as there might be room for improvement.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for your kindly reply! I think the bottleneck is the speed of `I/O` and I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you timed `cdo expr,'new_var=rad_temp+1' in.nc out.nc` for comparison?  These are big files, Data I/O is likely your bottleneck irrespective of the method used.